# Can you use Firebase Auth and Firebase Analytics in the same Xamarin.IOS project?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app with Firebase Auth integration. I've set up Dependency Service for Android and iOS to create a new user when prompted. The Android dependency works fine, but whenever I call any 'Auth' method in my iOS dependency, the app crashes on startup with the following error thrown from my "Firebase.Core.App.Configure()" line in my delegate file:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
>
> Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:
>   -[FIRApp setGetTokenImplementation:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282d3d1a0

...followed by a mile-long stack trace

My current iOS Dependency code is below:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ActNearMe; //name of my app
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.InstanceID;
using Firebase.Core;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IFirebaseInterface))]
namespace ActNearMe.iOS
{
    public class FirebaseInterface : IFirebaseInterface
    {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    NameValueCollection sendingData;

    public void CreateNewUser(string email, string password, NameValueCollection userData)
    {
        //sendingData = userData;

        //Anytime I call anything with Auth here, the app won't even load.
        Console.WriteLine(Auth.CurrentVersion);


        //Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password,(authResult, error) => { 

        /*client.UploadValuesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("it's done!");


        };
        client.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri("http://www.cvx4u.com/anm_web_services/create_user.php"), sendingData);
        */

       //});

    }




    }

}
```

Here is my error log:

```
2019-04-15 10:18:53.724 ActNearMe.iOS[6964:1670900] +[FIRApp    registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1060d1bb8
2019-04-15 10:18:53.724 ActNearMe.iOS[6964:1670900] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRApp registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1060d1bb8'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22401c518 0x2231f79f8 0x223f3e2c4 0x224021d60 0x2240239fc 0x2231f9ffc 0x2231fbe54 0x106626390 0x106638314 0x106637370 0x10663742c 0x1066266d8 0x10662b2a0 0x106625044)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Application 'com.russjowell.actnearme' terminated.
Launched application 'com.russjowell.actnearme' on 'iPhone (2)' with pid 6964
```

**UPDATE**
So I've been playing around with turning things on and off, omitting certain lines of code and such. I'm also using Firebase Analytics with my app, and when I remove the Firebase iOS NuGet Analytics package from my Xamarin.iOS project, things work fine, but when you use both Analytics and Auth packages together, the crash resumes. So I guess my new question is:
Is it possible to use both Firebase iOS Auth and Firebase iOS Analytics in the same project? Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with with the NuGet packages.

That internal method exists in v5.1.8 but not in v5.2.0.

For now, please, downgrade to 5.1.8

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/245

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the object that was supposed to handle the message has been disposed.

This is potentially a problem with the bindings, or the way that a callback was provided to Firebase.

It is not possible to diagnose the problem purely from the snippet you have, so a quick work around is to do the following:

Whatever object is passing a C# object to Firebase likely needs to be kept on a static global variable.   This will ensure that it does not get disposed.

Comment: If it helps, anytime I call anything under "Auth" in my iOS dependency (for example, just "Console.WriteLine(Auth.DefaultInstance.Description);," I get these problems. However, as soon as I remove the calls to Auth, the issue is resolved. I need to make the Auth calls b/c I'm using Firebase for authentication.